# Why does esp move 0xC down after 1 push in this x86 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I wrote this small program to measure how far esp is decremented after a push. The entire program is not in here but the relevant part is:

```
format PE console
entry main
include 'macro/import32.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable
msg db "The esp address is: %.8X\n", 0
p db "pause>nul", 0
some_num dd 0

section '.code' code readable executable

main:
mov eax, esp
push ebp ; store caller's base ptr
mov ebp, esp ; Set this func's base ptr
push eax
push msg
call [printf]
push esp
push msg
call [printf]
```

The two addresses which get printed to the console are 0xC apart from one another, rather than 4 as the description of the x86 `push` instruction claims.

Comment: Because you aren't cleaning up the stack after each of the `printf` calls. If you push 2 4 byte arguments (8 total0 on for printf you have to add 8 bytes after (usually something like `add esp, 8`). by not cleaning up after each call you keep pushing data to the stack without removing the old data.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh Michael, thank you sir... Total n00b assembly mistake. Ah well, ya live and learn. I neglected to view the pushes to the prinfts as pushes and realize that they are factored into the math.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Petch's comment made me understand the answer to this question. The problem was that I had to use the push instruction in order to call printf which was causing esp to be decremented a few extra times. The below code accomplishes the goal because it cleans up the stack after the first printf and also uses eax to save esp at the right state:

```
format PE console
entry main
include 'macro/import32.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable
msg db "The number is: %.8X\n", 0
p db "pause>nul", 0
some_num dd 0

section '.code' code readable executable

main:
mov eax, esp
push ebp ; store caller's base ptr
mov ebp, esp ; Set this func's base ptr
push eax
push msg
call [printf]
add esp, 8
mov eax, esp
push eax
push msg
call [printf]
```

By using `add esp, 8` we appropriately relieve the stack of the two pushes to the first call to printf such that esp is back in the original position that it was to be measured at. We then save esp in eax immediately so that the following pushes do not tamper with the measurement state. The results confirm that push does indeed subtract 4 from esp.

Comment: `push esp` pushes the value *before* the `esp-=4` happens, so `mov eax,esp` / `push eax` can simplify to `push esp` when there are no stack operations in between.